# PIC18F4550, button and counting code

Tags: microcontroller

I am using PIC18F4550. I have some problem about the counting. How should i write the code when i press the button the counting were add 1?

this is my code

```
#include <P18F4550.h>
#include<xlcd.h>                //built-in LCD library
#include<delays.h>
#define BB PORTBbits.RB0
#pragma config FOSC = XT_XT, PWRT = ON, MCLRE = ON
#pragma config BOR = ON, WDT = OFF, PBADEN = OFF, LVP = OFF
void DelayPORXLCD(void) //15mS delay
{
    Delay1KTCYx(15);
}
void DelayFor18TCY(void) //18 cycle delay
{
    Nop(); Nop(); Nop(); Nop();
    Nop(); Nop(); Nop(); Nop();
    Nop(); Nop(); Nop(); Nop();
    Nop(); Nop(); Nop(); Nop();
    Nop(); Nop();
} 
void DelayXLCD(void) //5mS delay
{
    Delay1KTCYx(5);
}
void main(void)
{
    unsigned char minute [] = "00";
    unsigned int i = 0;
    ADCON1=0x0F;            //PORTA digital
    TRISD=0;                //outputs
    TRISB=0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 =1;

    OpenXLCD(EIGHT_BIT & LINES_5X7); //LCD set-up

    while(BusyXLCD( ));
    WriteCmdXLCD(0x0C); //on display, off cursor

    while(BusyXLCD( ));
    SetDDRamAddr(0x82); //character start position

    while(BusyXLCD( ));
    WriteCmdXLCD(SHIFT_DISP_LEFT); //cursor moves right
                              //for each character

    putrsXLCD("Adjust minute");     //string placed in ROM

    SetDDRamAddr(0xC6);
    putsXLCD(minute);

    for(;;)
    {
        if(BB == 0)
        {
             minute++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: somebody can help me? i am trying many day but  still cannot work as well

Comment: Please format your code properly. Use the `{}` button and make sure that your indents are correct. Check the preview before you submit your question. You should remove any code that is not related to your problem.

Comment: my program is correct ,at the button that side i can't to make it

Comment: i have seen arduino program but i have a lot not understand about the program , because i am using microcontroller.

Comment: Sorry. I got mixed up which controller you are using. I will delete the Arduino comment. You should be able to find button examples for PIC.

Comment: after the code if(BB == 0) i write minute++, but on LCD it can't work properly

Comment: Then put that information in your question and explain what *does* happen. What does `for(;;)` do when you have no variables?

Comment: this is that thing i confuse what should i write in there , when i write minute++ but it can't work

Comment: Where's the code for reading the button?

Comment: i have define the button on top

Comment: i have make a unsigned char minute[] = "00"; to show the 00 at lcd but  how should i write a code when i press the button the 00 were become 01 until 99?

Comment: i write minute++ at the button when i push, but can't work.

Comment: So, in your infinite loop you are incrementing the counter. But where do you display it after modification?

Answer (score 1):

You're not displaying the number on the LCD during updates. This could be one of several problems. But you can try:

```
for(;;)   // And empty <for> will loop forever, just like while(True)
{
    if(BB == 0)
    {
         minute++;         // BUG. This variable is a string. See updated answer
         putsXLCD(minute); // Write the updated number to the LCD
    }
}
```

With this you will still have bouncing problems. The minutes will increase several times with a single button press.

**Update**

The `minute` variable should be an integer. You can't do math on strings, only on numbers. So do the math on a number, and convert it to a string. Try:

```
unsigned int minute = 0;
char minute_str [5] = "0";

for(;;)   // And empty <for> will loop forever, just like while(True)
{
    if(BB == 0)
    {
        minute++;
        sprintf (minute_str , "%d", minute);
        putsXLCD(minute_str); // Write the updated number to the LCD
    }
}
```

Seems like you still need to understand a few programming basics. I would try to start with something *much* simpler than a microcontroller.

Comment: i try it cannot make the program its show warning (suspicious pointer conversion,scalar type expected for increment operator) what is this mean?

Comment: I updated my question with the second answer.

Comment: also cant , but it can build success , on the LCD the number 0 why its show a symbol not 0?

Comment: i am a newbie on microcontroller  i can do it show the character on lcd ,its just can't to do a counting when button is push

Comment: You also need to add #include <stdio.h> to your includes, otherwise sprintf() will not work. Also: show us a schematic of how you connected the switch.

Comment: the switch 1 pin connected to RB0 another pin connected to GND

Comment: yes i have added #include<stdio.h> also cannot work properly , but why the int 0 show at lcd is a symbol not a number?

Comment: You proably need a pull-up resistor of 10K or so between RB0 and Vcc - otherwise, the input may not go High when the button is not pressed.

Comment: The inpur is go high, when i try to press the button it can close the display, just cannot change the number, i think i have some problem in the program